# Java contains method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, boolean, contains

I have a problem with a *contains (...)* method from *List <...>* class. I'm trying to check if a expression (that is loaded from user input) already exist in a List, but if I entered same name as twice, it said there's nothing same in the List. Please help, there's source code:

```
boolean checker;

checker = expressions.contains(line[1]);

if (checker == true) {
    System.err.println("This expression has already been declared!");
    return index;
}
```

*PS: **line[1]** is a second index in array from main function that stores user-entered line split by whitespaces. (First index of **line** need to be always 'var', and second is any word that cannot be twice in the List)*

Comment: What is the type of `expressions`? What is the type of `line[1]`? Have you overridden `equals`? Please show a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem - we can't help you with so little information.

Comment: So you mean , `expressions` list already has `line[1]` and it is returning false ?

Comment: You clarification is not exactly clear. N.B. writing `if(checker == true)` is the same as writing `if(checker)` just uglier and more error prone.

Comment: Why not use a `Set<String>`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I tryed many, many ways, I wrote my own contains method, but it always returned the same result.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Why not use a Set<String>? And why not use Collection<String>?! Because it always returns false, with any method, any class, and it always returns false!

Comment: Post more code. You have not found a new JDK bug.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch (and Jon Skeet) There's a link to full program: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kLb0V2eu)

Answer (score 0):

Your list may not have exact same string as provided in the input which may be due to white spaces. Try trimming the input and then call contains

```
 checker = expressions.contains(line[1].trim());
```